# Is it illegal to quote the C++ Standard Draft?

Tags: discussion, copyright, citation

I recently edited an answer from another StackOverflow user in order to clarify some parts it by adding some quotes from the [C++14 Standard Working Draft *(N4296)*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) - the user however rolled back my edit immediately and told me to "not add copyrighted text" to the answer.

Am I infringing the copyright *(and committing a crime)* when citing the Standard Working Draft? I've seen many answers containing quotes from the Standard Working Draft on StackOveflow before, and I also think it would be really unfortunate to be unable to cite it.

Does citing the Standard Working Draft fall under "Fair Use" for nonprofit educational uses? Or should I avoid doing it and edit out answers that cite the Standard Working Draft?

Comment: Ask your lawyer :)

Comment: IANAL but I think you have committed a crime, yes, based on [this](http://www.isrm.gov.mk/en/images/upload/Direktivi%20i%20pravilnici/28.iso_policy_for_the_protection_of_iso_s_intellectual_property.pdf), particular article 5. Unless you are an ISO member.

Comment: `Does citing the Standard Working Draft fall under "Fair Use" for nonprofit educational uses?` SE isn't a non-profit.  It's a for-profit business and it's posts are commercial activities.

Comment: @rene Section 8.2 specifically refers to drafts (which this is) and states that a particular citation (which is provides the exact text needed for) has to be applied whenever its referenced.

Comment: @Servy oh boy, I don't think we want that in every answer, even if it was allowed.

Comment: @rene It's one fairly short line of text; not exactly that bad.  And it's not exactly our choice; it's either properly citing it or not quoting it at all.  We can't just choose to not cite it.

Comment: I *think*, perhaps with some slight rewording (esp. to take the focus off of *you* and *your* actions and place it more on relevant laws and such), this *might* be askable over on http://law.stackexchange.com/, but don't quote me on that, I'm completely unfamiliar with how things work on that site.

Comment: Many major standards bodies predate the internet, some by many decades. They developed a closed, copyrighted system for their standards, so that people who bought copies of the standard would help pay organization overhead. To many of us nowadays, it almost sounds oxymoronic to have a non-open standard, but that is what history has left us with.